# XSLT 1.0 / sorting for-each results with a condition

Tags: loops, sorting, xslt

How can I sort the output of for-each loop results so, that elements with certain condition (certain sub-element having a value) are sorted to top of the results and after those, the rest in top-down order of the XML.

My sample XML here looks like this

```
<waybill>
<shipment>
    <parcel>
        <sscc>SSCC1</sscc>
        <consignee>Receiver1</consignee>
        <date>Date1</date>
        <status>Status1</status>
    </parcel>
    <parcel>
        <sscc>SSCC2</sscc>
        <consignee>Receiver2</consignee>
        <attention>Note2</attention>
    </parcel>
    <parcel>
        <sscc>SSCC3</sscc>
        <consignee>Receiver3</consignee>
    </parcel>
    <parcel>
        <sscc>SSCC4</sscc>
        <consignee>Receiver4</consignee>
    </parcel>
    <parcel>
        <sscc>SSCC5</sscc>
        <consignee>Receiver5</consignee>
        <attention>Note5</attention>
        <date>Date2</date>
        <status>Status2</status>
    </parcel>
    <parcel>
        <sscc>SSCC6</sscc>
        <consignee>Receiver6</consignee>
        <attention>Note6</attention>
    </parcel>
</shipment>
</waybill>
```

And the with here would be to have for-each - loop generated into  - level so, that it would first list those with value in  - element and then rest.

So the desired output would be:

```
SSCC2;Receiver2;Note2
SSCC5:Receiver5;Note5
SSCC6;Receiver6;Note6
SSCC1;Receiver1
SSCC3;Receiver3
SSCC4;Receiver4
```

I know how to build the for-each loop in general, but how the sorting of the output is defined?

I have only XSLT 1.0 so the solution should only use that...

Edit:  My XSLT looks like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
    <xsl:output method="text" version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each select="waybill/shipment/parcel">
            <xsl:value-of select="sscc"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="consignee"/>
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="attention"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:sort select="number(boolean(attention))" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:sort select="count(attention)" data-type="number" order="descending"/>
```

Comment: Hi. I added the XSLT into the original question (sorry to miss that in the first place...). Where in that you put that sorting line?

Comment: The `xsl:sort` instruction must be the first child of `xsl:for-each`.

Comment: Thanks. now I got it! :)